# Views only used for not logged user

Tags: views

Is there a way to only display a view result for Not Logged user.

If yes, How I could perform this.

I'm using drupal 7

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view's settings (Page settings/Block settings) find **Access**. Change **Permission** to **Role** and select appropriate role (*anonymouse*)